# How to get the value of an array that's inside another array

Tags: php

I have this:

```
Array
(
  [28] => Array
    (
        [name] => HTC Touch HD
    )
)
```

There's only one array inside the main array and I only the value of name. Problem is that I don't know the index (28).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `array_values` just in general to get rid of any weird keys:

```
$normal = array_values($arr);
$normal[0]['name']
```

Or in this particular case, `end`, which is only a little bit hacky:

```
end($normal)['name']
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/cApBjK

(Yep, `reset` and `first` and such work too.)

Comment: This is a good approach. Although this will duplicate the array, generating unnecessary memory clutter. It's better to catch the essence and only find out what the `key` is and call it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use

```
$array = array_pop($array);
```

And then to get the `name` element:

```
$array['name']
```

Comment: As this is, it wouldn't work. -- Even after the edit, this still wouldn't work.

Comment: @MattPsyK Yeah I realised it was a bit hacky. Changed it :)

Comment: You know you still only return the array, your answer doesn't get the answer as in the original question.

Comment: I disagree on that. But, I've edited my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    reset($outerArray);
    $innerArray = current($outerArray);
```

Now you should have access to the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self-explanatory  :)

```
<?php
$array = array(
    28 => array(
        'name' => 'HTC Touch HD'
    )
);

$key = current(array_keys($array));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array[$key]);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know the structure of an array, you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct.